# Create a new array based on a relationship between elements in an existing array in ruby

Tags: ruby

I have the following array:

```
a = [1, 2, 6, 10, 11]
```

and I want to return a new array `b` that consists of the sums of adjacent elements that differ by one. In this case, the returned array would be:

```
b = [3, 21]
```

i.e. `a[0]` and `a[1]` differ by one, so sum them and add `3` to `b`.

`a[3]` and `a[4]` differ by one, so sum them and add `21` to `b`.

Update

I've made a mistake:

```
a = [1, 2, 6, 10, 11, 12]
```

It should return:

```
b = [3, 33]
```

Comment: Show something that you have tried already

Comment: I haven't tried anything. I can easily generate the code to do this myself but I'm looking for a Ruby way using ruby array methods.

Comment: It would have been much nicer, if you would have shown the code that could easily generate, and asked what is the ruby way of doing it.

Comment: @RamJet I've updated my answer so now it works for arrays like: `[1,2,1,3,5,6] #=> [4,11]`, it would fail previously.

Comment: Downvoter - What's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work with Ruby v1.9+.

```
arr = [1, 2, 6, 6, 10, 11, 12]

arr.drop(1).
    each_with_object([[arr.first]]) { |n,a| (a.last.last - n).abs == 1 ?
      a.last.push(n) : a.push([n]) }.
    reject { |a| a.size == 1 }.
    map(&:sum)
  #=> [3, 33]
```

Here's a variant that allows us to skip the step `reject { |a| a.size == 1 }`. (I thought this might be of interest even though I don't think I'd advocate it.)

```
e = (arr + [Float::INFINITY]).to_enum
a = [[e.next]]
loop do
  n = e.next
  (a.last.last-n).abs==1 ? a.last.push(n) : (a.push([n]) if (n-e.peek).abs==1)
end
a.map(&:sum)
  #=> [3, 33]
```

When the iterator is at the end and `n #=> Float::INFINITY`, `e.peek` raises a `StopIteration` exception which [Kernel#loop](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Kernel.html#method-i-loop) handles by breaking out of the loop.

Comment: That's a clever answer for Ruby v1.9+. I should point out that Sebastián Palma answer works with Ruby 2.2+ and sagarpandya82 answer works with Ruby 2.4.1+

Answer (score 4):

You can initialize a `b` variable and use `each_cons`, taking two consecutive elements from the array, then use `map`, inside you can get the sum of those two values per array if the substraction of both values is equal to 1, as you'll get `nil` values then you can compact the "mapped" result:

```
a = [1, 2, 6, 10, 11]
b = a.each_cons(2).map do |value|
  value.reduce(:+) if value[1] - value[0] == 1
end.compact
# => [3, 21]
```

Here's an update, you can use `slice_when` and convert to array the enumerator that you get as result, then to map the `sum` of each array element that has more than one value inside, and the compact in order to remove `nil` elements:

```
p arr.slice_when{|a, b| b != a.next}.to_a
# => [[1, 2], [6], [10, 11, 12]]
p arr.slice_when{|a, b| b != a.next}.to_a.map{|e| e.sum if e.size > 1}
# => [3, nil, 33]
p arr.slice_when{|a, b| b != a.next}.to_a.map{|e| e.sum if e.size > 1}.compact
# => [3, 33]
```

But this looks better using `select` and mapping the `sum` of elements at the end:

```
p arr.slice_when{|a, b| b != a.next}.to_a.select{|e| e.size > 1}.map(&:sum)
```

A benchmark:

```
arr = [1, 2, 6, 10, 11, 12]

Benchmark.bm do |bm|
  bm.report do
    iterations.times do
      arr.slice_when{|a, b| b != a.next}.to_a.map{|e| e.sum if e.size > 1}.compact
    end
  end

  bm.report do
    iterations.times do
      arr.slice_when{|a, b| b != a.next}.to_a.select{|e| e.size > 1}.map(&:sum)
    end
  end

  bm.report do
    iterations.times do
      arr.chunk_while { |a,b| b == a.next }.select{ |a| a.size > 1 }.map{|e| e.reduce(:+)}
    end
  end
end

    user     system      total         real
0.920000   0.010000   0.930000 (  0.942134)
0.920000   0.010000   0.930000 (  0.939316)
0.940000   0.010000   0.950000 (  0.964895)
```

Comment: each_cons is the method I was looking for. Thanks

Comment: If `a = [1, 2, 6, 10, 11, 12]` then your technique returns `[3,21,23]`. I think it should return return `[3,33]`.

Comment: Could be a bit less confusing with `do |a, b|` and avoiding the array refs.

Comment: @sagarpandya82 that's right. I didn't consider that. So how do you do it?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `[3,21,23]` @sagarpandya82? it says "I want to return a new array, (b), containing the sum of _adjacent_ elements that differ by one"

Comment: @SebastiánPalma RamJet seems to agree with me. _adjacent elements that differ by one_ can be more than two elements in a row. I don't think `each_cons` can be used here.

Comment: @RamJet, I had to update the answer, take a look, thanks everyone.

Comment: Nice update. I also suggest you use `(a-b).abs != 1` as your block condition, so that `[1,2,1,7,6] #=> [4,13]`. I only realised this afterwards but 'difference by one' could be negative of course.

Comment: Both sagarpandya82 and @Sebastián Palma have answers that are correct. Thanks to both of you. Only one problem. I'm using ruby 1.9.3 and both of these methods need a later version of ruby to work.

Comment: There's a good argument for your interpretation of "sum of adjacent elements". Given that interpretation, using `each_cons(2)` is a good choice.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `chunk_while`. It 'chunks' adjacent elements if they differ by `1` (using the test @SebastiánPalma has but with `abs`). See [Ruby documentation](http://ruby-docs.org) for more information about these methods.

```
a.chunk_while { |x,y| (x-y).abs == 1 }.select{ |a| a.size > 1 }.map(&:sum)
#=> [3, 21]
```

Note: [`Array#sum`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-i-sum) can only be used in Ruby >= 2.4. Use `inject(&:+)` otherwise:

```
a.chunk_while {|x,y| (x-y).abs == 1 }.select{|a| a.size > 1}.map {|a| a.inject(&:+)}
```

#### Steps

```
a.chunk_while {|x,y| (x-y).abs == 1 }  #actually returns an enumerator.
#=> [[1, 2], [6], [10, 11]]

a.chunk_while {|x,y| (x-y).abs == 1 }.select{|a| a.size > 1}
#=> [[1, 2], [10, 11]]

a.chunk_while {|x,y| (x-y).abs == 1 }.select{|a| a.size > 1}.map(&:sum)
#=> [3, 21]
```

Comment: I have ruby 1.9.3. chunk_while doesn't work with that version of ruby. Any suggestions?

Comment: @RamJet Go with Cary's answer:) Looks good.

Answer (score 1):

iterate through each element, initialize var 'sum' to elem if sum is nil. When difference between elem and next is one, add next elem to sum and store in sum, increment seq so we know there was at-least one with diff as 1.

Do this until the diff b/t elem and next is not 1, when diff is not 1 push the sum to res array if seq > 0 and reset sum to nil and seq to 0. This only takes O(n).

```
a.each_with_object([]).with_index do |(x, res), i|
     sum ||= x 
     if a[i+1] && (x - a[i+1]).abs == 1 
       seq += 1
       sum += a[i+1]
     else
       res << sum if seq > 0
       sum = nil
       seq = 0
     end
end
```

Comment: When you write an answer, you should also include some indication of what the code *does*. Otherwise, it's up to a (potentially novice) reader to try and decipher it, which isn't terribly useful.

Comment: thanks, updated answer with description.